# Tengo un warnig "mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given

Tags: php, mysql

Este es mi codigo de conexion el cual me marca error.

```
    <?php 
// Constantes conexión con la base de datos
define("servidor", "localhost");
define("userdb", "root");
define("passdb", "");
define("bd", "sistema_reservacion");
define("puerto","3306");
// Variable que indica el status de la conexión a la base de datos

$errorConexionDB = false;
// Verificar constantes para conexión al servidor
if(defined('servidor') && defined('userdb') && defined('passdb') && defined('bd')&& defined('puerto')) {

    // Conexión con la base de datos
    $mysqli= new mysqli(servidor,userdb,passdb,bd);
    $conectado=mysqli_init();
    $conectado->real_connect(servidor,userdb,passdb,bd,puerto);




    // Verificamos si hay error al conectar
    if(mysqli_connect_error()){
        $errorConexionDB = true;

    }

    // Evitando problemas con acentos
    $mysqli -> query('SET NAMES "utf8"');
} 

function Conectarse(){
    if (!($link=mysqli_connect(servidor,userdb,passdb))) {
        echo "Error conectando a la base de datos.";
        exit();
    }

    if (!mysqli_select_db(bd, $link)){
        echo "Error seleccionando la base de datos.";
        exit();
    }
    return $link;
}

$link = Conectarse();


mysql_close($link); //cierra la conexion

?>
```

Nose cual se a el detalle si alguien puede ayudarme se lo agradeceria mucho, el error es este "Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\hotel2\includes\conexion.php on line 38
Error seleccionando la base de datos."

Comment: Tienes código innecesario. Ya selecciona la base de datos aquí  `$mysqli= new mysqli(servidor,userdb,passdb,bd);` (es el último parámetro). No necesitas seleccionarla de nuevo. Tampoco necesitas init, con new ya estás conectando a la BD. También mezclas los estilos de programación y eso solo crea confusión en el código. Por los métodos que usas parece que has aprendido usando tutoriales o código arcaico que convendría optimizar, limpiar y mejorar.

Answer (score 1):

Es demasiado confuso ese código. Debes decidir si vas a trabajar orientado a objetos o por procedimientos. Si bien, funciona con ambos, por convención [no se deben combinar estilos](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php).

Siguiendo con las convenciones de estilo, las [constantes deben ir en mayúscula](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.constants.php). Las mismas tienen un ámbito global en el script.

El código que describes hace 3 conexiones a la base de datos sin ninguna razón.

También se hace comprobación innecesaria a las constantes (`if(defined('servidor') && ...`). Si están definidas explicitamente en el script, ¿para qué las vas a comprobar?
Tendría un poco más de sentido si las constantes estuviesen en otro archivo, `config.php` (por ejemplo) y lo llamas con `require` o `include`.

Según la [documentación oficial](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.mysqli.php), podrías [conectar la base de datos](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.construct.php) de la siguiente forma (estilo orientado a objetos).

```
<?php 
// Constantes conexión con la base de datos
define("DBSERVER", "localhost");
define("DBUSER", "root");
define("DBPASSW", "");
define("DB", "sistema_reservacion");
define("DBPORT","3306");

$link = new mysqli(DBSERVER, DBUSER, DBPASSW, DB, DBPORT);
    if ($link->connect_errno) {
    exit('Falló la conexión: '. $link->connect_error);
}
$link->set_charset("utf8");
```

Con eso el script está listo para hacer consultas a la base de datos.

```
$query = "SELECT ...";
$result = $link->query($query);
```

Una vez que haya terminado la ejecución del script, PHP [cerrará automáticamente la base de datos](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.close.php), pero por cuestiones de optimización puedes hacer el cierre explicito si ya no vas a usar más el controlador de base de datos.

```
$link->close();
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta. Lo único es que no se recomienda mostrar mensajes de error internos como `$link->connect_error` (aunque el Manual lo use de ejemplo). Hay que evitar eso, porque se puede revelar información que algú hacker con más o menos destreza puede explotar para atacar el sistema en caso de error.

Answer (score 0):

El uso correcto de `mysqli_select_db` es:

```
mysqli_select_db ( mysqli $link , string $dbname ) : bool
```

y lo tienes cambiado. Esa línea debe ser:

```
if (!mysqli_select_db($link, bd)){
...
```

Tienes otro error al cerrar la conexión a la base de datos, debe ser:

```
mysqli_close($link); //cierra la conexion
```